# How to grab data from other class Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I have to create two classes, let's call them A and B .

```
public class A {

    double Number1;
    double Number2;

 A(double Number1, Number2){
        this.Number1=Number1;
        this.Number2=Number2;
}
}
```

Now i have a void main class where someone enter their Number 1 and Number 2

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
A game=new A(555, 999);
}
```

Now, i Want to Create another Class Called B, and i want the Numbers 555, and 999  to be transferd/to use the same values into class B
like

```
public class B{
///double a= 555;
///double c= 777;

}
```

I need these operators a, and c to fetch data from public static void main class
Can someone explain me how to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Where to start? Shot form: Create a constructor for class `B` whi takes an object of `A` as his parameter and define getter and setter.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to add some get methods into `A`:

```
public double getNumber1() {
    return Number1;
}

public double getNumber2() {
    return Number2;
}
```

And add set methods into `B`:

```
public void setA(double a) {
    this.a = a;
}

public void setC(double c) {
    this.c = c;
}
```

Then instantiate `B` in your main class:

```
B b = new B();
```

And set the values then:

```
b.setA(game.getNumber1());
b.setC(game.getNumber2());
```

Now the values of `a` and `c` of your instance of `B` are `555` and `999`.

Or perhaps:

```
public B(double a, double c) {
    this.a = a;
    this.c = c;
}
```

and pass the values into the constructor:

```
B b = new B(game.getNumber1(), game.getNumber2());
```

Answer (score 1):

One basic principal of OOP is that we have certain objects with certain properties build upon classes. These classes 'act as blueprints' for objects which should use their behaviour.

As I mentioned in a comment you could create a constructor who takes an object of class `A` as a parameter:

```
public class B
{
  private double value1;
  private double value2;

  public B( A aObject )
  {
    value1 = aObject.getVal1();
    value2 = aObject.getVal2();
  }
  // rest of the class...
}
```

with a class A:

```
public class A
{

  private double val1;
  private double val2;

  public A( double val1, double val2 )
  {
    this.val1 = val1;
    this.val2 = val2;

  }

  public double getVal1()
  {
    return val1;
  }

  public double getVal2()
  {
    return val2;
  }
}
```

and a main method:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
  A aObject = new A( 100, 100 );
  B bObject = new B( aObject );
}
```

Doing so would alow objects of class `A` to exist on their own but objects of class `B` always need a 'foundation' in form of another object from which they can copy their values.

Also take a small read on [encapsulation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm)

Comment: In my opinion class B is poor design, you bind your class B to class A to only fetch the values, and not referencing the object by member variable.

Comment: The reason is, you need a new constructor for any class you want to get the values from. You event don't, if your constructor expect the values only.

Comment: @ChristophS The design may be flawed but I has two strong positive points. You can **only** use an object of class `A` as a source for the values and it caputes the **current** state of the object. Yes you would need to overload the constructor for any new class but it wasn't a requirement of OP.  The question states to copy the values from A to B. Using setter would allow a user to instantiate a empty object of `B` which shouldn't be possible if its values have to depend on other ones. Also it's **a** solution not **the** solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need getter methods in you classes to query the values. In your case for the member variables Number1 and Number2.

Here is an example for you, consider the change of upper-/lowercase names:

```
public class A {
  // value of number 1
  // member variables should start lowercase
  // they should be private so they are not modified from the outside
  private double number1;

  // value of number 2
  private double number2;

  // constructor:
  public A(double number1, double number2) {
     // in a custom constructor you should 
     // alwas run the superconstructor at first:
     super();
     setNumber1(number1);
     setNumber2(number2);
  }

  // setter/getter for number 1:
  // search the internet for "camelcase" description
  // (lower/upper cases in method/member names)
  public void setNumber1(double theNumber) {
    this.number1 = theNumber;
  }

  public void getNumber1() {
    return this.number1;
  }

  // do the same for number 2
}
```

Now, you can use these getters to retrieve the data. Build class B the same way and you go like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
  A a = new A(555, 666);
  B b = new B(a.getNumber1(), a.getNumber2());
}
```

Useless to say that in this example class A and class B don't differ, so class B is nonsense. But if your classes are going have different signatures (member variables, methods and so an), this is a proper way.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend A class on B. The code bellow will help you out.

```
public class ClassA {

    double number1;
    double number2;

    public ClassA(double number1, double number2) {
        this.number1 = number1;
        this.number2 = number2;
    }

}

public class ClassB extends ClassA {

    public ClassB(double number1, double number2) {
        super(number1, number2);
    }

    public double getNumber1() {
        return number1;
    }

    public double getNumber2() {
        return number2;
    }

}
```

If you access the classB.getNumber1() method you will get your results.

Comment: I don't like the extends. You don't always want to extend a class, and the question did not mention any correlation between the classes. Just write the getters into class A